# How do I make and end screen when my player class collide with one of my platform class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I been trying to make an end screen but I do know how, I have watched some tutorials but none of them really make's sense to me. I have also tried using my start screen but switch it up a little bit and putting it in a different spot but it dose not work. I am trying make it was when my player collides with one of my platforms the end screen shows up but I do not know how to make an end screen.

```
I do not know what to really put here but this is my start screen code 
##############################################
#START MENUE

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Jump", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",100,350,100,50,green,darkgreen,main_loop)
        button("Quit",300,350,100,50,orange,darkred,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
        
############################################
```

```
my Full code




import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

#this is screem height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

#know we put screem name
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs first Game")





bg = pygame.image.load("New.png")

gg = pygame.image.load("lol.png")

Rule2 = pygame.image.load("one1.png")

Rule1 = pygame.image.load("two2.png")

Rule3 = pygame.image.load("three3.png")

Rule4 = pygame.image.load("four4.png")

Rule5 = pygame.image.load("five5.png")

Rule6 = pygame.image.load("six6.png")

#player class
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

class platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("Rock.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//2,self.ss1.get_height()//2))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20 , self.y,58,60)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)

        player_rect = self.ss1.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        player_rect.centerx += 70
        player_rect.centery += 88
        window.blit(self.ss1,player_rect)
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20 , self.y,58,60)

class item:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("H6.png")
        self.ss1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.ss1,(self.ss1.get_width()//2,self.ss1.get_height()//2))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.ss1,self.rect)
        
        
class wall:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


#draw player
white = (255,255,255)
player1 = player(255,400,30,30,white)

darkred = (200,0,0)

darkgreen = (0,200,0)

black = (0,0,0)
item1 = item(200,-500,50,50,white)
item2 = item(250,250,50,50,white)
item3 = item(330,-1030,50,50,white)
item4 = item(400,-2290,50,50,white)
item5 = item(300,-1600,50,50,white)
item6 = item(200,130,50,50,white)
item7 = item(230,-1830,50,50,white)
item8 = item(300,0,50,50,white)
item9 = item(330,-1440,50,50,white)
item10 = item(20,-160,50,50,white)

items = [item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10]

green = (0,255,0)
orange = (255,0,0)
platform1 = platform(100,300,10,60,orange)
platform2 = platform(5,200,10,60,orange)
platform3 = platform(5,400,10,60,orange)
platform4 = platform(100,100,10,60,orange)
platform5 = platform(5,-50,10,60,orange)
platform6 = platform(100,-200,10,60,orange)
platform7 = platform(5,400,60,600,orange)
platform8 = platform(300,-2430,10,60,orange)
platform9 = platform (350,-340,10,60,orange)
platform10 = platform (100,-470,10,60,orange)

platform13 = platform(330,-600,10,60,orange)
platform14 = platform(100,-790,10,60,orange)
platform15 = platform(330,-990,10,60,orange)
platform16 = platform(70,-1130,10,60,orange)
platform17 = platform(200,-1340,10,60,orange)
platform18 = platform(400,-1500,10,60,orange)
platform19 = platform(300,-1700,10,60,orange)
platform20 = platform(100,-1950,10,60,orange)
platform21 = platform (350,-2140,10,60,orange)
platform22 = platform (100,-2270,10,60,orange)
platform23 = platform(0,-2500,60,500,green)


#walls
platform11 = wall (485,-9600,10000,10,orange)
platform12 = wall (0,-9600,10000,10,orange)
wall1 = wall (0,400,60,500,orange)
wall2 = wall (0,-2500,60,500,green)
wall3 = wall (485,-9600,10000,10,orange)
wall4 = wall (0,-9600,10000,10,orange)


walls = [wall1,wall2]



platforms = (platform1,platform2,platform3,platform4,platform5,platform6,platform7,platform8,platform9,platform10,platform13,platform14,platform15,platform16,platform17,platform18,platform19,platform20,platform21,platform22,platform23)


                    
fps = (60)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()








##############################################
#START MENUE

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        window.fill((255,255,255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Jump", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",100,350,100,50,green,darkgreen,main_loop)
        button("Quit",300,350,100,50,orange,darkred,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
        
############################################



def main_loop():
    
    #window
    def redrawwindow():
        window.fill((0,0,0))

        window.blit(bg,(0,0))
    

        #draw plyer
        player1.draw()
        platform11.draw()
        platform12.draw()
        wall3.draw()
        wall4.draw()
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.draw()
        for wall in walls:
            wall.draw()
    



        # the score draw it on the screen
        window.blit(text,textRect)

        for item in items:
            item.draw()

            
    font  = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
    score = 0
    text = font.render("Coins = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ((100,40))

                    
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
              

            #walls
        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform11) and player1.rect.colliderect(platform12):
            player1.x = 40

            # this makes you scroll up
        if player1.y < 250:
            player1.y += 1
            #platforms
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.y += player1.speed

            for item in items:
                item.y += player1.speed

            for wall in walls:
                wall.y += player1.speed
                #walls
            platform11.y += player1.speed
            platform12.y += player1.speed

            # this makes you scroll down
        if player1.y > 450:
            player1.y -= player1.fall
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.y -= player1.fall
            platform11.y -= player1.fall
            platform12.y -= player1.fall


            for item in items:
                item.y -= player1.fall

            for wall in walls:
                wall.y -= player1.fall
        




         # coin collisions
        for item in items:
            for one in range(len(items)-1,-1,-1):
                if player1.rect.colliderect(items[one].rect):
                    del items[one]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render("Coins = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
                    textRect.center = ((100,40))
        



        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a]and player1.x > player1.speed:
            player1.x -= player1.speed

        if keys[pygame.K_d]and player1.x <500 - player1.height - player1.speed:
            player1.x += player1.speed

        if keys[pygame.K_w]and player1.y > player1.speed:
            player1.y -= player1.speed

        if keys[pygame.K_s]and player1.y <500 - player1.width - player1.speed:
            player1.y += player1.speed

        if not player1.isJump:
            player1.y += player1.fall
            player1.fall += 1
            player1.isJump = False

            collide = False
            # this part lets you jump on platform
            for platform in platforms:
                if player1.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                    collide = True
                    player1.isJump = False
                    player1.y = platform.rect.top - player1.height + 1
                    if player1.rect.right > platform.rect.left and player1.rect.left < platform.rect.left - player1.width:
                        player1.x = platform.rect.left - player1.width
                    if player1.rect.left < platform.rect.right and player1.rect.right > platform.rect.right + player1.width:
                        player1.x = platform.rect.right

   
                

                if player1.rect.bottom >= 500:
                    collide = True
                    player1.isJump = False
                    player1.JumpCount = 10
                    player1.y = 500 - player1.height

            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    player1.isJump = True
                player1.fall = 0


        else:
            if player1.JumpCount >= 0:
                player1.y -= (player1.JumpCount*abs(player1.JumpCount))*0.3
                player1.JumpCount -= 1
            else:
                player1.JumpCount = 10
                player1.isJump = False
        
        
        redrawwindow()

        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform6):
            window.blit(Rule3,(-150,-80))
            
        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform2.rect):
            window.blit(Rule1,(-30,0))
            
        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform23.rect):
            window.blit(gg,(100,100))
            
        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform7.rect):
            window.blit(Rule2,(-70,0))

        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform1.rect):
            window.blit(Rule4,(-40,100))

        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform14.rect):
            window.blit(Rule5,(-50,0))

        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform17.rect):
            window.blit(Rule6,(-50,0))

    
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
game_intro()
main_loop()
```

Comment: create a function that displays your end screen, and if the players collide, instead of calling redrawwindow(), call the new function.But make sure you are not calling it once, but in every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a framework that might help you out.  Along same lines as comment above.  You need a boolean variable to keep track of when to show the end screen (something bad happened) and then use it to decide which screen to draw in your main loop...

```
def redrawwindow():
    # basically what you have now...

def draw_end_screen():
    # make this new function such that it shows your end-screen


run=True
end_condition=False   # a new boolean variable to keep track if collision (or something else happened)

while run:
    # basically what you have now....

    # check for collision (in pseudo-code) check for game-ending events
    if player1.collides_with_death...:
        end_condition=True
    if player1.falls_into_pit()...:
        end_condition=True

    # use the boolean variable to decide what to do next, and in next loop
    if end_condition:
        draw_end_screen()
    else:
        redrawwindow()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Awesome.  If it was helpful and you don't need any further answers on this, you could "accept" the answer by hitting the greyed out checkmark to close the question.